# how to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp to work on numpy array inputs with coupled differential equations in vectorized manner

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, vectorization, differential-equations

Suppose I want to solve a list of equations, but they are not coupled, just defined differently by numpy arrays. For example, I have

`y'(t) = 2*t + c`

where c is just a known constant given in numpy array, e.g., `c = np.array([1, 2])`. This means that I need to solve 2 equations, possibly also with different initial values. This can of course be easily solved analytically.

`y(t) = t^2 + c*t + C`

where C is another constant dependent on the initial value at `y(0)`. For example, first equation has `C = y(0) = 0`, sendond equation has `C = y(0) = 1`. Then I can get exact solution:

```
y =  t^2 + 1*t
y =  t^2 + 2*t + 1
```

If I want to use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` to get the value at `t=1`, I can then "pretend" that they are coupled. Specifically, the code looks like

```
def test_fun(t, y):
    c = np.array([1, 2])
    dy1 = 2*t + c
    return dy1
sol = solve_ivp(test_fun, [0, 1], np.array([0, 1]))
y = sol.y[:, -1]
```

This actually works giving me `y = np.array([2., 4.])` which matches what would give analytically.

But now suppose I have a list of equations with constants differently a numpy array, but also each of them consists of 3 coupled differential equations. Let's still use a toy example, which they are not really "coupled", but just needs to return multiple values in the functions as what you would do when solving coupled differential equations

```
def test_fun(t, y):
    c = np.array([1, 2])
    dy1 = 2*t + c
    dy2 = 3*t + c
    dy3 = 4*t + c
    return dy1, dy2, dy3

sol = solve_ivp(test_fun, [0, 1], np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]]))
```

But now it will complain that `ValueError: y0 must be 1-dimensional.` Flatten y0 does not seem to make sense, because I want the input to the function to be an array of size 2, but for each element, it will return a system of 3 coupled equations. If I just flatten, it will just assume it is the input to a system of 6 coupled equations, and then complain `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (6,)`

Of course I can just use a for loop, but the general idea is to avoid it as it is very slow in python, and my `c` array is very large.

Comment: Yes, your last system should give you a state vector of dimension 6. You would need to put 3 copies of the initial vector into the initial state, `np.concatenate` is your friend here. Another function for dimensional manipulations is `np.reshape`, also available as method of an array.

Comment: When working with scipy functions like this, you have to play by its rules.  If the doc and error says `y0` has to be 1d, you can't pretend otherwise.  The only 'vectorization' in `solve_ivp` is this coupled sense.  True numpy vectorization means using the compiled array methods.  It's a relatively low level process.  Here you are trying to avoid a high-level python loop, so the notion of 'vectorize' does not apply.  Your `test_fun` has to be run many times, in a loop chosen by `solve_ivp`.  Nothing is "vectorized".

Comment: can't you test for your self if it's faster to do one flat set, versus separate call for each coupled set?

Answer (score 1):

*"Flatten y0 does not seem to make sense, because I want the input to the function to be an array of size 2, but for each element, it will return a system of 3 coupled equations. If I just flatten, it will just assume it is the input to a system of 6 coupled equations, and then complain ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (6,)"*

You would have to flatten `y0` before it is passed to the solver.  Then `test_fun` will get the flattened vector, so in `test_fun` you would reshape `y`, do the calculation with the array, and then flatten the array of derivatives before returning it from `test_fun`. (In your simple example, `y` is not used, so you wouldn't have to reshape it.)  When the solver returns, you'll also have to reshape the result so it looks like an array of arrays.

I created a package called [`odeintw`](https://pypi.org/project/odeintw/) that does this for you, but it uses [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), not `solve_ivp`.  Here's how your script might look if you used `odeintw`:

```
import numpy as np
from odeintw import odeintw


def test_fun(t, y):
    c = np.array([1, 2])
    dy1 = 2*t + c
    dy2 = 3*t + c
    dy3 = 4*t + c
    return dy1, dy2, dy3


n = 250
t = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y0 = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]])
sol = odeintw(test_fun, y0, t, tfirst=True)
# The numerical solution `sol` is an array with shape (n, 3, 2).
```

You'll have to run some tests to see if this approach is any faster than running a Python loop over the individual systems.  (To improve the performance, you could try implementing the `Dfun` parameter of `odeint`.  See the `odeintw` docstring for how it must be implemented.)